# Is the creation of a Database, User and assigning privileges using evolutions a bad practice in Play?

Tags: database, playframework

It is possible to manage database structures using [evolutions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Evolutions#Managing-database-evolutions) in Play. In the example I only see examples of creating tables. May the creation of users, assigning privileges and creating databases reside in these scripts as well or is it a bad practice and why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to have your application connect to the database using a super user on the database. You could run into trouble with cases of sql injections, or if someone gains access to the database login/password.

As evolutions are mainly used by an application, and so use the same user account, it is recommended to have a separate user account with little privileges on the database.

Evolutions by themselves are quite modular and could be used by themselves to manage a database (if the user facing applications use other users). But there may be more complete tools that may do the same job, like [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)